# onActivityResult never called from widget launched activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-widget, android-fileprovider

I'm new here. I discover how StackOverflow works.

I'm creating a new android homescreen widget. My widget has a button. When pressed, it starts an activity (it's not a configure Activity, just a standard activity). In this activity, I have a test button. My purpose is to create a text file after pressing this test button.

In onCreate function, I have this code to handle the button :

```
final Button testButton = findViewById(R.id.button_test);
    test.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(WidgetActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                    Utils.MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

            String fileName = "test.txt";
            Intent exportIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT);
            exportIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            exportIntent.setType("text/plain");
            exportIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, fileName);
            startActivityForResult(exportIntent, FILE_EXPORT_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    });
```

And I have this function :

```
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode != RESULT_OK)
        return;

    switch (requestCode) {
        case FILE_EXPORT_REQUEST_CODE:
            if (data != null) {
                Uri uri = data.getData();
                if (uri != null) {
                    Context c = WidgetActivity.this;

                    ParcelFileDescriptor pfd = null;
                    try {
                        pfd = c.getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(uri, "w");
                        Preferences.export(mAppWidgetId, pfd.getFileDescriptor(), WidgetActivity.this);
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

onActivityResult is never called.

I put this code in my MainActivity, and it works very well.

I don't know how to achieve this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's seems to be impossible.

The way I achieve this :

1. My widget starts its activity (not the MainActivity), as usual, and one feature offer the possibility to create a file.
2. The button in this activity create a new intent with action code, and launch MainActivity.
3. MainActivity use action code to decide what to do : execute code to create the file.
4. MainActivity have a onActivityResult called when user choose a file name and a directory.